# Ubuntu randomly freezes

Tags: unity, crash, lockup

This has been an issue I have experienced since Ubuntu 14.04.  I have attempted a number of fixes (lost track as I've literally tried 20+) all to no avail.  It's completely random when it happens and I can't exactly place what is triggering it.  I could simply be surfing the web in Chrome or Firefox, or I could be doing an Android build and it will freeze.

Each time it happens, I have no keyboard or mouse functionality so I can't try to kill processes.

I have seen this on a few different hardware configurations, but they each have AMD processors and chipsets in common.

Machines were all stock voltages and speeds. No over clocking involved.

First machine specs:
AMD Phenom II x6 1090t 3.2GHz 
Gigabyte GA-870-UD3 motherboard (AMD 870 chipset)
16GB Kingston HyperX DDR3 1600MHz
Samsung 840 Pro Series 250GB SSD
Nvidia GT240 1GB PCI-e

Second machine specs:
AMD FX 8320 3.5GHz
Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3 motherboard (AMD 970 chipset)
16GB Kingston HyperX DDR3 1600MHz
Samsung 840 Pro Series 250GB SSD
AMD 7770 1GB PCI-e (also had Nvidia GTX 660 2GB in this configuration)

Now these specs do share some common parts. However, when I was using Ubuntu 17.10 it happened, but using Ubuntu Gnome 17.10 these freezes absolutely do not happen.  I believe it to be something with Unity, but I'm at a loss as  to where to start trying to track down causes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is with 14.04, 14.10, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10, 18.04, and 18.10 and these freezes are only with Unity installed.

Comment: This sounds like you need a new flashplayer, certain Firefox flashplayer will eat up a lot of resources, some will even keep Firefox open once Firefox is closed, I'm pretty sure that's your issue, unless you got a lot of add-ons, and toolbars mixed with heavy Web page scripts

Comment: Type in about:about I think it's called about:plugins but I'm not 100% to which one you have, then I'd research it. We all know adobe is the best, but it's extremely limited on Linux...

Comment: I'll look into that but I'm pretty positive that's not going to cause a lock up that requires a hard shutdown

Comment: Firefox running at 100% eating up resources don't leave room for anything else to run on the system, then you have ever thing waiting, but some flash players are just trash... I had it happen where I had to do a hard shut down for a week until I found it

Comment: If you have a USB that isn't configured or is faulty it can use 100% too causing the system to freeze

Comment: I had only keyboard and mouse connected via USB both of which are Logitech. I'll look into flash as I know on M$ systems it can be problematic.

Comment: When it freezes, I assume you still have a frozen image on the screen? Is the system still reachable via network from another PC then? Also, it may help running a graphical system monitor such as gkrellm on the desktop so you can spot if something unusual is happening when the freeze happens. (I'm trying to track down a similar problem, but not sure it is the same issue.)

Comment: Also: What are the time spans between consecutive freezes? Is it completely random? Does it vary a lot? When you say that "freezes absolutely do not happen", how long have you waited to verify that it does not freeze?

Comment: The freezes are usually at least 5 minutes after boot, but after that the time is completely random. I've left the machine over night to verify lock up at times.  It's only when I run stock Ubuntu with unity. Ubuntu Gnome can be left booted for weeks on end with no lock up at all.